# UIAlertController fails to show UIAlertView

Tags: xcode, swift, parsing, parse-platform

I want to show a `UIAlertView` when login credentials are wrong, but instead it just goes to the next view and doesn't show the `UIAlertView?`

It says invalid login credentials but seems to ignore the error.  I tried a custom segue but it was calling itself when the button was pressed.  I didnt do not `self.presentsegue` so is it the code.  If reachability  is not the problem, just checking if the user is connected to the internet, thats not a problem.

```
func login()
{

    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        activityLoader.alpha = 1
        activityLoader.startAnimating()
        let emailText = EmailTextBox.text

        PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(EmailTextBox.text!, password: PasswordTextBox.text!){(user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if user != nil
            {
                //Login Successfully
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(emailText, forKey: "UserSaved")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

                self.activityLoader.alpha = 0
                self.activityLoader.stopAnimating()


                let title = "Successfully logged in"
                let message = "Enjoy"
                let okText = "OK"

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let OKbutton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(OKbutton)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


            }
            else
            {
                self.activityLoader.alpha = 0
                self.activityLoader.stopAnimating()

                let title = "Please try again"
                let message = "Check your login credentials"
                let okText = "OK"

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let OKbutton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
                alert.addAction(OKbutton)
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        self.activityLoader.alpha = 0
        self.activityLoader.stopAnimating()

        let title = "No Internet Connection"
        let message = "Please ensure you are connected to the Internet"
        let okText = "OK"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let OKbutton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(OKbutton)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


}


@IBAction func LogInPressed(sender: AnyObject)
{

    if self.EmailTextBox.text == "" ||  self.PasswordTextBox.text == ""
    {
        let title = "Please try again"
        let message = "Check your login credentials"
        let okText = "OK"

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let OKbutton = UIAlertAction(title: okText, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(OKbutton)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else
    {
        login()
    }
}
```

Comment: "*It says invalid login credentials but seems to ignore the error.*"  Where does it say "invalid login credentials"?  That string doesn't appear in your program.   Also, what do you mean by "the error"?

Comment: "*I didnt do not `self.presentsegue` so is it the code.*"  That is **very** difficult to understand.  Can you clarify?

Comment: "*If reachability is not the problem, just checking if the user is connected to the internet, thats not a problem.*"  That is also very difficult to understand.  Can you clarify that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see in your Storyboard file that there is no segue from the button to the next view controller.